# Why can't I switch geometry based on instance index?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm attempting to create a clock using geometry nodes and want to use roman numerals. I have elected to instance the appropriate models of I V and X based on the instance index around a 12 pointed mesh circle. I thought I could use the geometry switch node by evaluating the index but my initial 'testing the theory' node setup is giving me a red line and I don't understand why.

If I simply use values in the compare node it works fine. If I use the index node it shows this error. Does the index node not simply output an integer? What am I missing?

Blender v3.6.1

[image: geometry nodes screenshot]
[image]

Comment: The _Switch_ node accepts only a single value as input. You are trying to feed it a list of in index values.

Comment: Got it, thanks!